# How to disable a mat-form-field in angular based on a value?

Tags: javascript, angular, types

How can we disable a matformfield , input field in angular ? . I want to disable the field based on test.status value ,  if status equal to 1 then this form is disabled. Thank you,

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="24px">
    <div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlexs>
        <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="description" matInput>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.description.hasError('maxlength')">
          Descriptions can't be more than 100 characters!
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

form builder group

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ ...
    status: [
        {
          value: test.status 
          disabled: true,
        }
    ],
    description: [
        test.description || null, [
          Validators.maxLength(100),
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: is `test.status` is independent variable ? or it is part of the form ?

Comment: its part of the form , but it is an independent field and has independent value

Comment: @programoholic , test.status is an independent variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`disabled` attribute will not work on  reactive form. You need to set the condition as below :

```
 this.formName = this.formBuilder.group({
  fieldName: [{value: 'someValue', disabled:(condition)}]
})
```

for example  :

```
 this.form = this._fb.group({
       description : [{value: 'someValue', disabled:(this.status>0)},[Validators.required]]
     })
```

When a form field is disabled , it is not included in the submitted values i.e form object.

You can get the values like below :

```
this.formName.getRawValue();
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gymmy1)

Comment: how I am going to insert the validators to it  Validators.maxLength(100) , I am receiving error when I include the validators

Comment: Validator is the second argument. Updated my answer

Comment: what do you mean sir by getting values like this.formName.getRawValue(); ? can you elaborate this one ?

Comment: @mark when you submit the form , `formname.values` contains values of all the fields. But when a control is disabled, form.values will not contain it's value. So if you need all the values including disabled ones. You should use the method which I have shared.

Answer (score -1):

Please append/use the below portion in your input-field html:

[disabled]="form.controls.status[0].value==1" 
(or)
[attr.disabled]="form.controls.status[0].value == 1? '' :null"
(or)
[class.disable]="form.controls.status[0].value == 1"

Hope this helps.